# CakePHP-One view to another view button click function

Tags: cakephp, file-upload

I am using CakePHP MVC. I have created two ctp templates inside View/Elements.Inside one ctp file I have added a button click function. On the other ctp file I have added the upload function of file to the database on button click. So now I am in need of help how to pass the button click function for file upload from the other ctp file.

Hope You guys can help.

Comment: specify your framework wersion on placing questions

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid to keep any logic in a template.
Look throw the example bellow:

```
class Photo extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'post_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric')
            ),
        ),
        'img_alt' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty')
            ),
        ),
        'rating' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric')
            ),
        ),
        'other' => array(
            'boolean' => array(
                'rule' => array('boolean')
            ),
        ),
        'img_url' => array(
            'uploadError' => array(
                'rule' => 'uploadError',
                'message' => 'Something went wrong with the file upload',
                'required' => FALSE,
                'on' => 'create'
            ),
            // custom callback to deal with the file upload
            'processUpload' => array(
                'rule' => 'processUpload',
                'message' => 'Something went wrong processing your file',
                'required' => FALSE,
                'last' => TRUE,
                'on' => 'create'
            ),
        ),
    );

    public function processUpload($check=array()) {
        if (!empty($check['img_url']['tmp_name'])) {
            if (!is_uploaded_file($check['img_url']['tmp_name'])) {
                return FALSE;
            }

            // build full filename 
            $filename = WWW_ROOT . $this->uploadDir . DS . $this->data['Photo']['post_id'] . DS . Inflector::slug(pathinfo($check['img_url']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'.'.pathinfo($check['img_url']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            // try moving file
            if (!move_uploaded_file($check['img_url']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
                return FALSE;

            // file successfully uploaded
            } else {
                $filename = WWW_ROOT . Inflector::slug(pathinfo($check['img_url']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'.'.pathinfo($check['img_url']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                // save the file path relative from WWW_ROOT e.g. uploads/example_filename.jpg
                $this->data[$this->alias]['filepath'] = str_replace(DS, "/", str_replace(WWW_ROOT, "", $filename) );
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have added the upload logic in controller only...I am calling the controller for upload process through ajax function. I just need to know that if I can call the upload button on click function from one ctp to another ctp

Comment: do you want to render some other ctp file's html as response? I don't realy get the idea...

Comment: Yes.You got it what I meant. I want to render the upload process from another ctp file

Comment: than you have to add a new template in your `view/Layouts` for example `ajax.ctp` and add `<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>` into it.
After, you have to use it every time when you need to to something with ajax and render it in your controller like `public function index()
    {
        $this->render('uploadTemplate', 'ajax');
    }`